# Gatsby Image data not coming through

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image, wp-graphql, gatsby-remark-image

I'm getting image data from WP passed into Gatsby.
I want to use Gatsby Image to improve performance.

Here's my GraphQL query:

[image: GraphQL Query]

But then when i console that data, I just get `sourceUrl` and `altText`.

[image]

I'm trying to pass my image from line 11 into the GatsbyImage component on line 22, but it's not working.

[image]